# Selenium Webdriver scraping, stale element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing a small scraping program, it navigates to a page with a list of links,

It clicks on the first link, opens a new page, gets some details, then navigates back to the page with the list of links,
it then tries to find the next link, but i get :

org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

any idea how i can avoid this ?

```
package scraping;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class yell {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

    }

    @Test
    public void verifySearchButton() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(
                "https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=1634428901&keywords=farmers&location=bedfordshire");

        List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a [@class='businessCapsule--title']"));

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        for (int i = 0; i < linkList.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(linkList.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href"));

            linkList.get(i).click();

            System.out.println("count start = " + i);

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            WebElement Add1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@itemprop,'streetAddress')]"));
            String Add1val = Add1.getText();

            WebElement Add2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@itemprop,'addressLocality')]"));
            String Add2val = Add2.getText();

            WebElement Add3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@itemprop,'postalCode')]"));
            String Add3val = Add3.getText();

            WebElement tel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'business--telephoneNumber')]"));
            String telval = tel.getText();

            System.out.println(Add1val + " , " + Add2val + " , " + Add3val + " , " + telval);

            driver.navigate().back();

            System.out.println("count end = " + i);

        }

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: For debugging try to increase Thread.sleep(10000) and get rid of if after you find the problem. On which code row does the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you follow the link, DOM is being reconstructed, causing every element you have in `linklist` to lose any relation to the current page, hence the `StaleElementReferenceException`.

If you want to visit all links listed on the first page, it's better to keep the links, not the elements themselves.

```
List<String> linkList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a [@class='businessCapsule--title']"))
  .stream()
  .map(element -> element.getAttribute("href"))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, when you have the list of links, instead of clicking a specific element, you can follow any subsequent link directly.

```
    driver.get(linkList.get(i));
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene ...

a great solution. ....working fine now...